# What could be the type of the imported aws-sdk object? (aws-sdk-js/ts/)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, typescript-typings

```
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk';

export default (env: any) => (context: Context): ###type of aws-sdk### => {
    (timeout config stuff)
    (connection config stuff)
    return aws;
}
```

I'm trying to use the aws-sdk as an object and need help with typing. I have some custom code for timeouts so I can't import aws-sdk directly.

Comment: Does it have to be typed? `any` would work.

Comment: @gonzo I have a tslint no-any rule. It forbids the use of any. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to refer to the type of `aws`, you can write `typeof aws`.  But in the example code you gave, you can just leave off the annotation and TypeScript will infer the return type of the inner arrow function to be the equivalent of `typeof aws` anyway.

As an example for a method signature:

```
public doSomething(awsInstance : typeof AWS) : void {
  // Do something with the AWS object.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. I can leave the type blank here, but later I defined the interface where the aws object goes into, and that is requiring a type definition. Do you think there is a way to "cheat" it by creating an interface for aws somehow?